# how to solve java.rmi.ConnectException in java program?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

i have created one simple java RMI program for understanding how it works.But when i trying to run my server side it raising the following exception.

**EDIT: We are using proxy connection...**

```
 Remote exception: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.7.150.18; nested exception is: 
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This is my Server side code for your reference...

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

public class SampleServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements SampleServer
{
  SampleServerImpl() throws RemoteException
  {
     super();
  }
    @Override
  public int sum(int a,int b) throws RemoteException
  {
     return a + b;
  }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      try
      {
        //set the security manager  
        //System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        //create a local instance of the object
        SampleServerImpl Server = new SampleServerImpl();
        //put the local instance in the registry
        Naming.rebind("//10.7.150.18:9999" , Server);
        System.out.println("Server waiting.....");
      }
      catch (java.net.MalformedURLException me) 
      {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + me.toString());  
      }
      catch (RemoteException re)
      {
         System.out.println("Remote exception: " + re.toString()); 
      }    
    }
}
```

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: Insufficient information provided. Are you getting this when binding? When looking up? Or when executing the remote method?

Comment: @EJP : when run this file using java.exe

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question, and the answer is right there in the stacktrace you should have posted, but if you mean that it happens when binding, it means the RMI Registry isn't running at that host on port 9999.

Answer (score 0):

The Naming class provides methods for storing and obtaining references to remote objects in a remote object registry. Each method of the Naming class takes as one of its arguments a name that is a java.lang.String in URL format (without the scheme component) of the form:

```
//host:port/name
```

add a name with in the URL format

```
//10.7.150.18:9999/Server
```

Comment: :we are using RMI in proxy environment.Is this cause any problem?

Comment: In Proxy environment? couldn't understand this completely. Is your server and client accessible from each other ? or do you mean to say you access your server using some proxy server?

Comment: @ Actually, our campus fully restricted internet access via proxy settings.So, now i am using client and server machines are in the same campus.Both server machines and client machines are working under proxy settings.what i do now?

Comment: So to access internet, you use some proxy server but for accessing server and client, you don't use any proxy ...Anyway, even in case there is a firewall or any proxy refer following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#firewallOut

Comment: There is nothing here that answers the question. -1.